# Can I safely add an external network to an existing NIC on XenCenter Pool?

Tags: networking, vlan, xencenter

We have 2 servers with 2 NICs each:

NIC 0 has our "Office Network" which is used by the Management interface and our VMs
NIC 1 has our "iSCSI Network" for storage

Both networks have no VLAN specified and are connected to switch trunk ports. The iSCSI network uses a standalone switch.

Can I safely add a new "Server VLAN" external network, specifying its VLAN ID, on NIC 0 without it affecting access to the management interfaces of the Citrix servers, or VM connectivity?

After moving our VMs to the new "Server VLAN" network, I would probably then plan to move the management interfaces to this VLAN also.

Hopefully this is very simple for someone to answer. I just want to make sure we don't lose access to the management interface and/or all the VMs! Thanks in advance.